# Azure Cosmos DB Integrated Cache re-use

Tags: azure, caching, azure-cosmosdb

When a query such as the one below is fired and cached:

If I fire this query again (within stale-time) but the max date has changed by 10 minutes, will the cache be used (where it can, but also hit the db for anything in the extra 10 minutes), or will the fact that a query parameter has changed result in a new cached entity (meaning we've completely skipped the previous cache)?

```
let items = await client
    .database("model-results")
    .container("historicals")
    .items.query({
      query:
        "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.partitionKey = @partitionKey AND (c.dataDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)",
      parameters: [
        {
          name: "@partitionKey",
          value: partitionKey,
        },
        {
          name: "@fromDate",
          value: min.toISOString(),
        },
        {
          name: "@toDate",
          value: max.toISOString(),
        },
      ],
    })
    .fetchAll()
    .catch((err) => {
      throw err;
    });
```

Comment: Turns out I've got a bigger problem, the cache isn't even being hit, despite repeated calls to the exact same query (above) with the exact same parameters. Looking at logs, the dedicated Gateway is definitely being hit, and "session" consistency is set on the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your query has different parameters, it will result in a cache miss. There is no "partial cache hit".

> **Query cache**
>
> The query cache can be used to cache queries. The query cache transforms a query into a key/value lookup where the key is the query text and the value is query results. The integrated cache doesn't have a query engine, it only stores the key/value lookup for each query.
>
> If the cache does not have a result for that query (cache miss), the query is sent to the backend. After the query is run, the cache will store the results for that query

You can probably check if the cache was used by checking the RU charge of your query.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/integrated-cache#query-cache